# How to calculate work and depth of a parallel algorithm

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing

I am working on a question to implement the Karatsuba Multiplication in parallel and then compare the work and depth of the algorithm against the time complexity of the same . I have searched through a few books that I have , I haven't found a way to calculate the work and depth . 
In terms of implementing Karatsuba multiplication, I'm trying to use a work pool . 
My two questions.:

How do I calculate work and depth of an algorithm ?
What other possible implementations can I use to efficiently parallelize the Karatsuba integer multiplication?